# How to get elements from new text field?

Tags: html, jquery

So I am working on some online agreements and I have a problem with getting products written on a downloaded .txt file. I don't know how to get the id of written products and get them into the file.
Currently the result shows "Products: undefined "

My code looks like this right now:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>New agreement</title>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        div {
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        input[type=text], textarea, select {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 12px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
        input[type=button]{ 
            width: auto;
            float: right;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 7px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
<b> Purchaser: </b>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtName" placeholder="Name and surname" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtAdress" placeholder="Adress"w/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtPersonalid" placeholder="Personal ID number" />
        </div>
         <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtPhone" placeholder="Phone number" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtextraAdress" placeholder="Additional Adress" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtpaymentAdress" placeholder="Payment e-mail adress" />
        </div>
         <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtDeadline" placeholder="Deadline" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtMoney" placeholder="Value with tax" /> 
          </div> <div>
            <select id="selTax">
            <opition selected value="">-- Choose your % of VAT --</option>
            <option value="8">8% VAT</option>
            <option value="23">23% VAT</option>
            </select> </div>
            
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtPrepaid" placeholder="Prepaid" />
            </div>
        <div>
            <textarea id="txtMsg" name="msg" placeholder="Additional message" style="height:100px"></textarea>
        </div>
        
        <b> Products: </b>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div id="workouts">
    <div class="workout">
      <input type="text" placeholder="New product">
    </div>
  </div>

  <button id="addWorkout" type="button">Add new</button>
</form>
<script>
  $("#addWorkout").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var last = $("#workouts").last().attr("id")
    template = "<div class='workout' id='workout" + parseInt(last[-1])+1 + "'> <input type='text' placeholder='New product'> "
    $("#workouts").append(template);
  });
</script>

        <div>
            <input type="button" id="bt" value="Download txt" onclick="saveFile()" />
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
<script>
    let saveFile = () => {
        
        const name = document.getElementById('txtName');
        const adress = document.getElementById('txtAdress');
        const personalid = document.getElementById('txtPersonalid');
        const phone = document.getElementById('txtPhone');
        const extraadress = document.getElementById('txtextraAdress');
        const paymentadress = document.getElementById('txtpaymentAdress');
        const deadline = document.getElementById('txtDeadline');
        const money = document.getElementById('txtMoney');
        const tax = document.getElementById('selTax');
        const prepaid = document.getElementById('txtPrepaid');
        //const workouts = document.getElementById('produkt');
        const msg = document.getElementById('txtMsg');
        
        
        let data = 
            '\r Name: ' + name.value + ' \r\n ' + 
            'Adress: ' +adress.value + ' \r\n ' + 
            'Personal ID: ' + personalid.value + ' \r\n ' + 
            'Phone: ' + phone.value + ' \r\n ' +
            'Additional adress: ' + extraadress.value + ' \r\n ' +
            'Payment adress: ' + paymentadress.value + ' \r\n ' +
            'Deadline: ' + deadline.value + ' \r\n ' + 
            'Value with '+ tax.value + '% TAX: ' + money.value + ' \r\n ' +
            'Prepaid: ' + prepaid.value + ' \r\n ' + 
            'Products: ' + workouts.value + ' \r\n ' + 
            'Message: ' + msg.value;
        
        
       
        const textToBLOB = new Blob([data], { type: 'plain/text' });
        const sFileName = 'Agreement.txt';

        let newLink = document.createElement("a");
        newLink.download = sFileName;

        if (window.webkitURL != null) {
            newLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);
        }
        else {
            newLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);
            newLink.style.display = "none";
            document.body.appendChild(newLink);
        }

        newLink.click(); 
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me with my code to put products value into downloadable txt file?

Comment: Your `workouts` variable is commented out? So `'Products: ' + workouts.value` would naturally result in "Products: undefined". Your question seems to jump all over the place, what specifically is the goal, and what are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your code. Happy coding...

```js
  $("#addWorkout").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var last = $("#workouts").last().attr("id")
    template = "<div class='workout' id='workout" + parseInt(last[-1])+1 + "'> <input type='text' placeholder='New product'> "
    $("#workouts").append(template);
  });


document.getElementById("bt").onclick =async () => {
        
        const name = document.getElementById('txtName');
        const adress = document.getElementById('txtAdress');
        const personalid = document.getElementById('txtPersonalid');
        const phone = document.getElementById('txtPhone');
        const extraadress = document.getElementById('txtextraAdress');
        const paymentadress = document.getElementById('txtpaymentAdress');
        const deadline = document.getElementById('txtDeadline');
        const money = document.getElementById('txtMoney');
        const tax = document.getElementById('selTax');
        const prepaid = document.getElementById('txtPrepaid');
        //const workouts = document.getElementById('produkt');
        const msg = document.getElementById('txtMsg');
        
        
        let data = 
            '\r Name: ' + name.value + ' \r\n ' + 
            'Adress: ' +adress.value + ' \r\n ' + 
            'Personal ID: ' + personalid.value + ' \r\n ' + 
            'Phone: ' + phone.value + ' \r\n ' +
            'Additional adress: ' + extraadress.value + ' \r\n ' +
            'Payment adress: ' + paymentadress.value + ' \r\n ' +
            'Deadline: ' + deadline.value + ' \r\n ' + 
            'Value with '+ tax.value + '% TAX: ' + money.value + ' \r\n ' +
            'Prepaid: ' + prepaid.value + ' \r\n ' + 
            'Products: ' + workouts.value + ' \r\n ' + 
            'Message: ' + msg.value;
        
        
       
        const textToBLOB = new Blob([data], { type: 'plain/text' });
        const sFileName = 'Agreement.txt';
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);
        let newLink = `<a href="${url}"  id="downloadLink" download="${sFileName}"></a>`
console.log(data)
console.log(textToBLOB,newLink)
        await new Promise((res,rej)=>{
            document.body.innerHTML +=newLink;
            res();
        }) 

        document.getElementById("downloadLink").click()
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>New agreement</title>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        div {
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        input[type=text], textarea, select {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 12px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
        input[type=button]{ 
            width: auto;
            float: right;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 7px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
<b> Purchaser: </b>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtName" placeholder="Name and surname" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtAdress" placeholder="Adress"w/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtPersonalid" placeholder="Personal ID number" />
        </div>
         <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtPhone" placeholder="Phone number" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtextraAdress" placeholder="Additional Adress" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtpaymentAdress" placeholder="Payment e-mail adress" />
        </div>
         <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtDeadline" placeholder="Deadline" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtMoney" placeholder="Value with tax" /> 
          </div> <div>
            <select id="selTax">
            <opition selected value="">-- Choose your % of VAT --</option>
            <option value="8">8% VAT</option>
            <option value="23">23% VAT</option>
            </select> </div>
            
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtPrepaid" placeholder="Prepaid" />
            </div>
        <div>
            <textarea id="txtMsg" name="msg" placeholder="Additional message" style="height:100px"></textarea>
        </div>
        
        <b> Products: </b>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div id="workouts">
    <div class="workout">
      <input type="text" placeholder="New product">
    </div>
  </div>

  <button id="addWorkout" type="button">Add new</button>
</form>

        <div>
            <input type="button" id="bt" value="Download txt"  />
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
<script>

</script>
</html>
```

I fixed an issue with downloading

Answer (score 0):

well for starters your line `const workouts = document.getElementById('produkt');` is commented out.
In addition, in that same line you have a typo in the word `product`.
I don't even see any text field with id of either `product` nor `produkt`, I assume that you're trying to create a new elements in runtime in the `workouts` div, I think that you should access the div (for example with `const workouts = document.getElementById('workouts');`)
and then iterate over its children, rather than trying to get the IDs of each runtime generated element.